# How to get 2 different numbers from a RNG that is being called to multiple times

Tags: c++

I am calling to a random number generator function twice and theoretically should be getting 2 random numbers each time but instead I am being given the same number both times.

I have tried calling to the function in different way and replaced the integer in srand to 0 and null but still receive the same answer

```
 int randomNUM()
 {
    srand(time(NULL));
    int RL = rand() % 100;
    return RL;
    RL = 0;
 }

 int main()
 {
     int RL = randomNUM();
     int RL2 = randomNUM();

     cout << "RL: " << RL << endl;
     cout << "RL2: " <<RL2 << endl;

 }
```

I expect the results for RL and RL2 to be completely randomized numbers between 1-99 but instead get the same number for each of them.

Comment: srand is guarantied to return the same number with the same seed. The likes of[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3032726/rand-generating-the-same-number-even-with-srandtimenull-in-my-main)

Answer (score 3):

You should only call `srand()` once, right at the beginning of your program. Once you call `srand()` the string of random numbers is reset.

Do something like

```
 int randomNUM()
 {
    int RL = rand() % 100;
    return RL;
    RL = 0;
 }

 int main()
 {
     srand(time(NULL));
     int RL = randomNUM();
     int RL2 = randomNUM();

     cout << "RL: " << RL << endl;
     cout << "RL2: " <<RL2 << endl;

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

`srand` sets the seed. You should do it once in main, not every time you want a random number. So instead, you should have

```cpp
 int randomNUM()
 {
    // removed srand(time(NULL));
    int RL = rand() % 100;
    return RL;
    RL = 0;
 }

 int main()
 {
     srand(time(NULL));
     int RL = randomNUM();
     int RL2 = randomNUM();

     cout << "RL: " << RL << endl;
     cout << "RL2: " <<RL2 << endl;

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are reseeding the random number generator each time you call `randomNUM()`.  Since it doesn't take much time between calls to `randomNUM()`, then the value that `time()` returns is the same both times.  As a result, the random number generator restarts the random number sequence at the same beginning point.  There are two ways you can solve the problem:

1. Move the call to `srand()` to be before all calls to `randomNUM()`
2. Have a `static boolean` value that you initialize to `false` and then set to `true` the first time you call `srand()`.  You can then check what the value of this variable is to determine whether you should call `srand()`.